# Objective C: Potential Memory Leak in code

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I ran the 'Analyze' on my code and the result shows a potential memory leak on the following part of my code

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

//Potential memory leak in code below
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I am not sure how to stop this leak. I tried to add a 'autorelease' to the back but that caused a crash. Any advise on this?

EDIT:

Screenshot of the leak message

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to alloc on NSURLConnection is returning an object with a reference count of 1.  Your code should be as following:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start]; // This is optional.  It should begin the request after you alloc it
```

After you are done with the object, you need to explicitly call:

```
[connection release];
```

Answer (score 4):

Release the connection object on success or failure. It needs to stay alive till then. So put a release in both `connection:didFailWithError:` and `connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate methods. Only one will get called. So retain-release will balance out.

Comment: Hi Deepak, I did what you advised and added the connection release in both the delegate methods. However I am still getting the memory leak message. I have updated my query with the screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: Although you create the connection object, you don't start the connection. Either use `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` and set `startImmediately:YES` or assign the object to a variable and then call `start` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the static method

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

instead of

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

of course there is NO need to release the connection object in it's delegate methods.

Or if you use the second method, release the NSURLConnection object in both delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

and can ignore the memory leak warning message.